# How to tell what is the aliased folder?

Tags: windows-7

In your home directory (C:\Users\%USERNAME%) there is a folder called "Application Data" that I've been told is an alias/synonym/hard-link to "AppData\Roaming"

So as I understand it "Application Data" doesn't really exist, it just "links to "AppData\Roaming"

How just by looking at the "Application Data" can I find out what it is an alias for? Right clicking on it and looking at Properties doesn't seem to reveal anything. The same goes for other aliases like "Local Settings"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see the properties because you don't have permission to view them as a standard user (UAC means that you view as a standard user by default, even if you're an admin).

In order to see where junctions go:

- open an administrative command prompt (go to the start menu, type `cmd`, then press ctrl-shift-enter)
- navigate to the directory containing the junction (in this case `C:\users\<username>\`)
- run `DIR -A:L` in order to show a list of junctions and where they link to. (you can use `DIR -A:HL` to just show hidden junctions, which will be a shorter list).

Comment: I didn't know they were called junctions! Thank you. Am I correct in referring to junctions as aliases/synonyms/hard-links? Or do those terms mean something different?

Comment: They are also aliases and synonyms, but "hard link" usually means two files pointing at the same data.